# Navigation drawer ondrawerOpen and Close not being called

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have created navigation drawer for my app and its working fine. But when I extended the main activity to a class to get the navigation drawer, the onDrawerOpen and onDrawerClose is not being called.

This is my activity to which i need the drawer

```
@Override
public void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about_us);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_us, null, false);
    mDrawerLayout.addView(contentView, 0);
}
```

And this is MainActivity

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(NavigationDrawerFragment.this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            System.out.println("Happy developer");
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            System.out.println("Happy Android");
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to initialise `new ActionBarDrawerToggle` with your main activity, which is `this`, not `NavigationDrawerFragment.this`.